# What do the one-letter prefixes in Ruby error messages mean?

Tags: ruby

Ruby error messages often contain lexical constants with one-letter prefixes, for example:

> syntax error, unexpected tIDENTIFIER, expecting kEND

Where do the `t` and `k` come from?  Are there other letters?  A master list of possible keywords?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For questions like this, [parse.y](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/trunk/parse.y) usually is the place to look. If memory serves, 't' stands for token whereas 'k' signifies a keyword.

Here's the different tokens that signify identifiers (in the sense of names for other things):

```
%token <id>   tIDENTIFIER tFID tGVAR tIVAR tCONSTANT tCVAR tLABEL
```

The only definition for `kEND` I found with a quick search was for `k_end`:

```
k_end : keyword_end
        {
          token_info_pop("end");
        }
        ;
```